# Why cannot trigger a function without setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I am using react native with react redux. Redux needs dispatch functions in actions and I writing this code in the actions. I am suspecting dispatch functions for this strange case.

When I call the function with setTimeout it is working but not working without setTimeout. Even it is not working call the function with setTimeout when has 100 ms.

```js
if (isJoinedNewGroup) {
     ;(async ()=>{
         //syncLocalGroupsAndGroupUsers is a async function.
         //It is fetching groups from API and saves the local database.
         dispatch(await syncLocalGroupsAndGroupUsers())

         //setMessagingGroupList setting messagingGroupList state.
         //working calling with when setTimeout has 500 ms:
         setTimeout(()=>dispatch(setMessagingGroupList()), 500)

         //Not working without setTimeout:
         //dispatch(setMessagingGroupList())

         //even not working calling with when setTimeout has 100 ms:
         //setTimeout(()=>dispatch(setMessagingGroupList()), 100)
         console.log("setMessagingGroupList() called isJoinedNewGroup: " + isJoinedNewGroup + " tel no: " + getState().validatedUserInfo.telNo)
     })()
}
```

Comment: Sounds like dispatch is not waiting. So put the setMessagingGroupList() in the end of syncLocalGroupsAndGroupUsers or await everything (PS: I am not coding react, just trying to think why this would happen)

Comment: @mplungjan Maybe I can do this. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#async-action-creators

Answer (score 0):

How about you do it like this?

```js
if (isJoinedNewGroup) {
     ;(async ()=>{
         //syncLocalGroupsAndGroupUsers is a async function.
         //It is fetching groups from API and saves the local database.
         await dispatch(syncLocalGroupsAndGroupUsers())

         //setMessagingGroupList setting messagingGroupList state.
         //working calling with when setTimeout has 500 ms:
         await dispatch(setMessagingGroupList())

         //Not working without setTimeout:
         //dispatch(setMessagingGroupList())

         //even not working calling with when setTimeout has 100 ms:
         //setTimeout(()=>dispatch(setMessagingGroupList()), 100)
         console.log("setMessagingGroupList() called isJoinedNewGroup: " + isJoinedNewGroup + " tel no: " + getState().validatedUserInfo.telNo)
     })()
}
```

Comment: No, it is not working. Thank you for your suggestions.